# How to open menu items from a separate element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I am trying to make my slider bar control my menu so that when you move the slider it opens the matching menu item. So when ATA 21 is shown on the slider, and the screen, you should also see that ATA open in the menu, an so on. I got the menu to open, but not the individual menu items. I tried simply using $("#target").click(); after opening the menu but that failed, so I tried using $("#target").addClass("mm-opened") and that also failed. However, neither approach gave any errors.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['rzModule'])

app.controller('projectController', function projectController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.slider = {
    value: 0,
    options: {
      floor: 0,
      ceil: 15, //defaults to rz-slider-model
      step: 1,
      precision: 0,
      minRange: 0,
      id: null,
      translate: function(value) {
        return 'ATA ' + value;
      },
      stepsArray: ['ATA 6-12', 'ATA 21', 'ATA 22', 'ATA 23', 'ATA 24', 'ATA 26', 'ATA 27', 'ATA 28', 'ATA 29', 'ATA 31', 'ATA 32', 'ATA 33', 'ATA 38', 'ATA 49', 'ATA 71-80', ],
      draggableRange: false,
      draggableRangeOnly: false,
      showSelectionBar: false,
      showSelectionBarEnd: false,
      hideLimitLabels: true,
      readOnly: false,
      disabled: false,
      interval: 350,
      showTicks: true,
      showTicksValues: false,
      ticksTooltip: null,
      ticksValuesTooltip: null,
      vertical: true,
      selectionBarColor: null,
      keyboardSupport: true,
      scale: 1,
      enforceRange: true,
      noSwitching: false,
      onlyBindHandles: false,
      onStart: function(value) {
        $scope.sliderATA = $scope.slider.options.stepsArray[$scope.slider.value];
      },
      onChange: function(value) {
        var api = $("#menu").data("mmenu");
        $scope.sliderATA = $scope.slider.options.stepsArray[$scope.slider.value];
        api.open();
        $("#ATA 21").addClass("mm-opened")

      },
      onEnd: null
    }
  };

  $scope.projectInfo = [];
  $scope.menuInfo = [];
  $http.get('config/Config.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.projectInfo = response.data[0].config;
    $scope.menuInfo = response.data[1].menu;
  });


  $scope.setImgPath = function(btnPath) {
    console.log(btnPath)
    $scope.activePath = "Assets/images/" + btnPath + "";
    console.log($scope.activePath);
  };
  $scope.contentCtrl = function(id) {
    $scope.active = id;
    console.log($scope.active);

  };

  $scope.closeMenu = function() {
    var API = $("#menu").data("mmenu");
    if ($("html").hasClass('mm-opened')) {
      API.close();
    }

  };
});
```

```css
/* Helvetica Font */

@font-face {
  font-family: HelveticaNeue;
  src: local('0'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf') format('otf');
}
body,
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#header {
  background: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
#footer {
  background: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 -1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 -1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.fa {
  color: #8ea5d0;
}
.fa:hover {
  color: #627EB0;
}
.fa:active {
  color: #415E95;
}
a:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
  color: #627EB0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.info_btn {
  color: #FFF !important;
  background-color: #8ea5d0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}
.info_btn:hover {
  background-color: #627EB0;
}
.info_btn:active {
  background-color: #415E95;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.info_btn:hover,
.info_btn:visited,
.info_btn:link,
.info_btn:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
#menu {
  background: #444444;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 10;
}
#menu .li {
  background: #555555;
}
#menu > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
#menu > ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
.menuBtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: #212121;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .25s linear, background-color .25s ease-in-out, border-color .25s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
}
.menuBtn:hover {
  background-color: #333333;
  outline: none;
}
.menuBtn:active {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #222222;
  outline: none;
}
#homeContent {
  color: #000000;
}
.secondary {
  text-indent: 3%;
}
.tertiary {
  text-indent: 6%;
}
.mm-listview .mm-next.mm-fullsubopen+a,
.mm-listview .mm-next.mm-fullsubopen+span {
  padding-right: 65px;
}
/* Global and Overrides */

#header {
  height: 96px;
  border: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
#menu {
  top: 96px;
  bottom: 72px;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 96px;
  bottom: 72px;
}
#footer {
  height: 72px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.fa {
  font-size: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.title {
  position: absolute;
  right: 75px;
  top: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.info_btn {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  right: 30px;
  top: 48px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 0 21.8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  right: 32px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#sliderContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  bottom: 75px;
  right: 32px;
}
/*  causes the color to change when you hover over a button of class myButton */

.revNum {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 12px;
}
.footer_info {
  bottom: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.6.1/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-slider/2.5.0/rzslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-slider/2.5.0/rzslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.6.1/js/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.6.1/wrappers/angular/jquery.mmenu.angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#menu").mmenu({
            "slidingSubmenus": false,
            "counters": true,
            extensions: ["multiline"],
            offCanvas: {
                position: "left",
                zposition: "front"
            }
        });
    });
  </script>


</head>


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="projectController">
  <title>Schematic Manual</title>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      
      <a class="fa fa-home" ng-href="#/home"></a>
      <h3 class="title">Schematic Manual</h3>
      <a href class="info_btn"><span>i</span></a>
      <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a ng-href="#/home" class="menuBtn">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><span class="menuBtn">ATA 6-12 - Aircraft General</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="menuBtn secondary" ng-href="#/schematicView">G650 Equipment Locator</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="ATA 21"><span class="menuBtn">ATA 21 - Air Conditioning</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="menuBtn secondary" ng-href="#/schematicView">AC Distribution System</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="menuBtn secondary" ng-href="#/schematicView">Pressurization System Wiring Diagram</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="menuBtn secondary" ng-href="#/schematicView">Air Conditioning System</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="menuBtn secondary" ng-href="#/schematicView">Air Conditioning Flow</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span class="menuBtn">ATA 22 - Auto Flight</span>
          </li>
          <li><span class="menuBtn">ATA 23 - Communications</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="menuBtn secondary" ng-href="#/schematicView">Aircraft Antenna Locator</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <a href="#menu" ng-click="closeMenu()" target="_self"><h1>MENU</h1></a>
      <div id="homeContent">
      <center>
        <h1>This is the home page</h1>
        <h2>{{sliderATA}}</h2>
      </center>
        </div>
      <div>
        <div id="sliderContainer">
          <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.value" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="revNum">Revision: 0.0</div>
      <div class="footer_info">Home page</div>
      <img class="logo" ng-src="./assets/images/{{projectInfo.logo}}">
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can't have spaces in element ID it is invalid. Also even if it wasn't,  the selector `$("#ATA 21")` would look for a tag `<21></21>` within element with `id="ATA"`

Comment: That fixed it., Thank you. I will remember that rule.